# C1005: Closure Compiler Warning (Parse error. name not recognized due to syntax error.) -- compression-input:

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

[WRN] C1005: Closure Compiler Warning (Parse error. name not recognized due to syntax error.)

CMD 7.6.0.87

after update from CMD 7.4.0.39

```
                                                                                                             .
```

with this configuration

```
 "compressor": {
     "type": "yui"
 }
```

Comment: Have you find the solution? I am getting the same message with the same version of CMD

Comment: I have the same issue! I am trying to upgrade from 6.6.0 to 7.6.0 and now I am getting this warning when I compile a page to the production version. These warnings didn't occur in 6.6.0.

Comment: Please do not close this issue! It is a valid problem that others encountered.

Comment: I tried to change configuration

`code`
"compressor": {
          "type": "closure",
          "compression": "advanced" // ADD THIS LINE
      }

`code`

but it isn't resolve

Answer (score 2):

There's no way anyone could tell you what's causing this w/o any source code to look at. You might want to pre-transpile your code with babel, which could provide more meaningful error messages. See https://medium.com/@thorstensuckow/sencha-ext-js-beyond-es5-a0382916b7a6

Comment: when I tried to use this extension I got: `node_modules/@coon-js/delorean/bin/bin.js:176`, `entries = entries.map(entry => {  TypeError: entries.map is not a function` when I ran `npx delorean -p`

Comment: @costa thanks for the comment. this has been fixed with v0.2.2

Comment: Retried it and it worked, thanks. What commands can I try now to make it spit more meaningful warning messages? Sorry, I haven't used babel

Comment: @costa Can you provide the configuration file you're using with your project? Of interest would be the js section thats telling closure input/output level. If Babel does not complain, transpiling succeeds so I'd guess there's something fishy going on between Sencha CMD & Closure.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please tell me exactly the file that you need? Is it the app.json?

Comment: I could send you a zip file with a new Sencha Architect 4.3.2  project I created. Alternatively, if you have SA, create a classic 7.6.0 project. There seems to be an issue with the SA, because I had to init the project manually using SenchaCmd 7.6.0. Once that's done, add viewport and a tab control in SA and save. Do a sencha app build, it returns lots and lots of warnings. Add delorean and go from there. If you don't have SA 4.3.2, you could create the app with SenchaCmd and then add the viewport and tabcontrol manually.

Comment: See this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74618163/sencha-architect-4-3-2-19-directory-does-not-contain-a-valid-framework

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't know that SA is involved, that seems to be more of an issue induced by SA, its dependencies and installation process. I suggest you join the Sencha Discord over at https://discord.gg/TW896RE32W - there are users more familiar with SA that can possibly help to sort the issues out.

Comment: Hey, thanks for recommending the discord channel. I didn't know it existed! FYI, I created a ticket for this issue. They said they already logged an issue in JIRA for it but they didn't provide a timeframe for fixing it. They recommended quieting the warnings, which I am not a fan of: `compressor: {"type": "closure", "warningLevel": "quiet"}`

Comment: `"compressor": {...`