# Sencha Architect 4.3.2.19 - Directory *** does not contain a valid framework

Tags: sencha-architect, extjs7

I installed and registered Sencha Architect 4.3.2.19. However, after I created a new classic ExtJs 7.6.0 project, it doesn't initialize Cmd properly, and in the command output I see:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-15"
com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: com.sencha.exceptions.ExState: Directory C:\Users\costa\Documents\Architect\frameworks/ext76/7.6.0.41/commercial does not contain a valid framework.
at com.sencha.tools.server.service.tasks.DispatchTask.execute(DispatchTask.java:55)
at com.sencha.tools.server.service.tasks.BaseServiceTask$1.run(BaseServiceTask.java:42)
at com.sencha.util.ThreadUtil$1.run(ThreadUtil.java:65)
at com.sencha.util.ThreadUtil$2.run(ThreadUtil.java:162)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: com.sencha.exceptions.ExState: Directory C:\Users\costa\Documents\Architect\frameworks/ext76/7.6.0.41/commercial does not contain a valid framework.
at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$InitCommand.validateEnvironment(AppCommands.java:1874)
at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$InitCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:1750)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:43)
at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.dispatch(BasePluginCommands.java:289)
at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
 
at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:80)
at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.dispatch(AbstractCommand.java:124)
at com.sencha.tools.server.service.tasks.DispatchTask.execute(DispatchTask.java:52)
... 4 more
```

The Cmd base directory is set to: `C:\Users\costa\bin\Sencha\Cmd` which contains the subdirectory `7.6.0.87`.

Any idea on how to fix the exception? Time to open a ticket?

Edit: I've got the previous error on Windows 2016. I just gave SA 4.3.2.19 for macosx a try. It has a different problem. I created a blank ExtJs 7.6.0 Modern project. When I save the project in the folder I get (I set the app name to `App`) :

```
/Users/costa/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.6.0.87/extensions/sencha-service/shell-wrapper.sh: line 41: cordova: command not found
/Users/costa/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.6.0.87/extensions/sencha-service/shell-wrapper.sh: line 41: phonegap: command not found
[INF] Initializing empty workspace at /Users/costa/Documents/development/javascript/TestAppModern01
[INF] Copying framework to /Users/costa/Documents/development/javascript/TestAppModern01/ext
[INF] Added framework ext to workspace.json
[ERR] The specified string cannot be converted into a valid namespace identifier
Exception in thread "Thread-61" com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: com.sencha.exceptions.ExState: Invalid namespace : App
at com.sencha.tools.server.service.tasks.DispatchTask.execute(DispatchTask.java:55)
at com.sencha.tools.server.service.tasks.BaseServiceTask$1.run(BaseServiceTask.java:42)
at com.sencha.util.ThreadUtil$1.run(ThreadUtil.java:65)
at com.sencha.util.ThreadUtil$2.run(ThreadUtil.java:162)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.sencha.exceptions.ExState: Invalid namespace : App
at com.sencha.util.NameUtil.stringToNamespace(NameUtil.java:76)
at com.sencha.command.generator.GeneratorCommands$AppCommand.validateAppName(GeneratorCommands.java:680)
at com.sencha.command.generator.GeneratorCommands$AppCommand.execute(GeneratorCommands.java:420)
at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$InitCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:1819)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:43)
at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.dispatch(BasePluginCommands.java:289)
at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:80)
at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.dispatch(AbstractCommand.java:124)
at com.sencha.tools.server.service.tasks.DispatchTask.execute(DispatchTask.java:52)
... 4 more
```

An identical error occurs when I save a classic project.

What am I missing? There seems to be something wrong overall with SA 4.3.2, or maybe it's missing something.

Both versions, windows & macosx, don't allow me to set `Build Tools` to `Enabled`. I click `Save`, I come back to the dialog and `Build Tools` is set to `Disabled`.

[image]

More than that, I downloaded ExtJs 7.6.0 and unzipped in a local folder, then in the above dialog I chose `Complete or Custom Path`, I entered the folder where I unzipped ExtJs, clicked Save, came back to the dialog and `Build Tools` is `Disabled` again.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found a workaround for the first problem I had on windows. I installed Sencha Cmd from the installer - I don't know if that made a difference or not.

After creating the classic app, and saving it in SA, I went to the command line and I ran inside the project folder: `C:\Users\costa\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.6.0.87\sencha.exe app init -n App -e ..\..\ext760 --classic`

You'd have to adjust the parameters according to your needs. I re-opened the project in SA, and it got its brains back. In my case I used a workspace, and the folder for the workspace was 2 levels up from the project folder. I placed the 7.6.0 ExtJs files in the ext760 directory.

Update: I created a ticket with Sencha and they came back with the fix.

The framework code has been incorrectly installed by SA 4.3.2 in this folder: `C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\Architect\frameworks\ext76\7.6.0.41\commercial\ext-7.6.0`. The solution is to copy the files in this folder one level up, i.e. in `C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\Architect\frameworks\ext76\7.6.0.41\commercial`, and then it's going to work.